# WebView Error on net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: android, webview, general-network-error

[image]

This is the code snippet that I use

```
final WebView webVu=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webVu.loadUrl("someURL");
webVu.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

I tried so many solutions like setting the correct date time and all on AVD.

Giving internet permissin in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

But nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is

http://www.ipchicken.com/

But there is no

https://www.ipchicken.com/

[image]

Wrong URL is the problem here

Comment: ah small mistake...the webpage doesn't fit in the webview ...I always get scrollbar ..Do you know how to solve the problem ? when I searched in the internet they say ..one has to include ViewPort meta tag in the web page...But it won't solve my problem anyhow.

Comment: This would do  `webVu.setInitialScale(100);`

Comment: As my answer is useful you could accept my post as answer and upvote it so that others will know if the answer is worthy and get benifited of it.